# inner html doesn't work in ie but works in ff

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
     {
        var Buffer= xmlHttp.responseText;     
        Buffer= Buffer.split("#%~");    
              document.getElementById("Template").innerHTML = Buffer[0];
              document.getElementById("Template1").innerHTML = Buffer[1];
              alert(Buffer+"Buffer");
```

The above code doenot work in ie but it works fine in ff. i tried even with other options but coulnt get it.
alert shows same values in ie & ff but its of no use as it doesnt print in ie. can anyone help?

Comment: You should use something like Mootools or jQuery to have better cross browser support. Even if the standard is "quite clear" browsers differentiate quite heavy.

Comment: What HTML element is `Template` and `Template1`?

Comment: How are you creating your `xmlHttp` object? They differ between browsers.. I guess what I'm saying is how are you convinced this is an `innerHTML` problem?

Answer (score 1):

internet explorer dont have the standart `XMLHttpRequest` object so you have to use the `ActiveXObject`

**sniplet from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)**

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

that makes sure httpRequest is working in IE aswell.
on a side note, you probly wanner look in to using `console.log` insted of `alert` then you get a nice output in youre developer tools (F12 on windows)

Answer (score 0):

You don't state this, but you need to be creating your `xmlHttp` object differently for certain browsers — especially Internet Explorer:

```
var xhttp = function(){
  var obj = null, er = null;
  if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'){
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {
    try{
      obj = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    }catch(er){
      try{
        obj = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }catch(er){
        obj = null;
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The usage of the following code would be:

```
xmlHttp = xhttp();
```

From then on you can use `xmlHttp` in roughly the same manner as you are doing, there are certain pitfalls / differences to be aware of, this is the reason why it is good to use a library as stated by Adrian.. however it is even better to understand the underlying differences first.